# How to use Eloquent search query by foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel, search, eloquent

i'm trying to make search box in (booking) table by searching in column(patient_id) and this column is foreign key to (patient) table  , and this column (patient_id) get the data of (patient_name) through foreach {{$booking->patient->patient_name }} , the problem is i don't know how to search in (patient_name) via (patient_id)in my controller (BookingController),Any Help? Sorry for my Language :(

this is my Booking Controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $search = \Request::get('search');

     $bookings = Booking::with('patient')->where('status','=', null)-
>where('patient_name','like', '%'. $search. '%' )->paginate(10);

     return view('booking.index')->withBookings($bookings);
}
```

my Booking Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Eloquent;

class Booking extends Eloquent
{

public function patient()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient'); 

}
}
```

my Patient model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Eloquent;
class Patient extends Eloquent
{
 public function booking()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Booking'); 

}
}
```

UPDATED ..This is index Page

```
    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET','url'=>'booking','class'=>'navbar-form navbar-left','role'=>'search'])  !!}
<a href="{{ url('booking.index') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add</a>

<div class="input-group custom-search-form">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default-sm" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-search"> <span class="hiddenGrammarError" pre="" data-mce-bogus="1"></span></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!} 
           <th>حجز باسم</th>
                        <th>القيمة</th>
                        <th>اسم الطبيب</th>
                        <th>النوع</th>
                    </tr> 
                  </thead>
                  <div ng-controller="myController">
                  <tbody>
                    @foreach ($bookings as $booking)
                          <tr ng-repeat="booking in bookings|filter:searching">
                            <td align="center">
                              <a href="{{route('booking.edit',$booking->id)}}" class="btn btn-default"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></a>
                              <a class="btn btn-danger"><em class="fa fa-trash"></em></a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs">{{$booking->id }}</td>


                 <th>{{$booking->booking_date }}</th>
                 <th>{{$booking->patient->patient_name }}</th>
                 <td>{{$booking->value }}</td>
                 <td>{{$booking->doctor_name }}</td>
                 <td>{{$booking->tybe }}</td>
                          </tr>
                @endforeach          
                        </tbody>
                </table>

              </div>
              <!--
              <div class="panel-footer">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col col-xs-4">Page 1 of 5
                  </div>
                  <div class="col col-xs-8">
                    <ul class="pagination hidden-xs pull-right">
                      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="pagination visible-xs pull-right">
                        <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            -->
            </div>
          </table>
<div class="text-center">
            {!! $bookings->links(); !!}
       </div>
</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$bookings = Booking::with(['patient' => function($query) use ($search){
     $query->where('patient_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
}])->where('status','=', null)->paginate(10);
```

OR if you are not sure about assign patient to all bookings so you should use query like this:

```
$bookings = Booking::whereHas('patient', function ($query) use ($search) {
     $query->where('patient_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
})->where('status','=', null)->paginate(10);
```

Comment: thanks Mohamed b  but i received the following error:   ErrorException
Undefined variable: search

Comment: @EsamMohamed I edited my answer check and test it again

Comment: the content of table loaded correctly but when search i received this error Trying to get property of non-objects

Comment: what do you mean about the content of table loaded correctly ?

Comment: before your edit , when i used a foreign key the table was show empty but after your edit the data show in table normally but when i type any name to search and click search i receive this error    ---> Trying to get property of non-objects

Comment: @EsamMohamed I think it related to your code in view , could you put booking.index blade file in your question?

Comment: @mohamed b , thanks for your efforts , i added Index page in Question

Comment: @EsamMohamed I suggest to do this for test search query ; copy the name of one patient_name column data and replace in where condition but instead of using like use this query and reload your index page ```$query->where('patient_name','=', 'name');```

Comment: same problem still existing

Comment: @EsamMohamed I update my answer check it and try second way

Comment: YOU ARE A GREAT MAN :) Its Working, Thank you sooooo much

Comment: @EsamMohamed it menas some of your booking has not patient_name,

Comment: No every Booking Have patient_name

Comment: can i search in more than one column ?

Comment: @EsamMohamed first of all if my answer is solution of your question you should check and choose it as answer

Comment: Yes, i know @mohamed b, i did it already but i should have 15 reputation to show my vote,but i checked your answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $keyword = $request->input('searchquery');
    $bookings= Booking::whereHas('patient', function($query) use ($keyword) {$query->where('patient_name', 'like', $keyword);})->get();
    return view('booking.index',compact('bookings'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

`dd($search);`

If you get search from some input try to use:

`$serach = $request->serach;`

Comment: Sorry, But where to add this?   yes the search working good but not with foreign key